# Multiple of same many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

***Note*** - So as to not cause confusion, the approach in the question works, but be careful of the use of `"s"`'s in your naming conventions.

I'm trying to have two many to many relationships between class `A` and class `B`.

**Approach**

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationship_a
  has_many :b, through: :relationship_a

  has_many :relationship_b
  has_many :other_b, through: :relationship_b, source: :b

end

class B < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :relationship_a
  has_many :a, through: :relationship_a

  has_many :relationship_b
  has_many :other_a, through: :relationship_b, source: :a

end
```

**Relationships**

```
class RelationshipA < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :A
    belongs_to :B

end

class RelationshipB < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :A
    belongs_to :B

end
```

And this is what happens:

```
2.1.2 :001 > B.new.otherA
ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughSourceAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find the source association(s) :A in model OtherA. Try 'has_many :otherA, :through => :relationshipB, :source => <name>'. Is it one of :A or :B?
```

If anyone is questioning my logic behind having two many-to-many relationships between the same classes, please do.

I have two objects, A and B. I have a main collection of A where there aren't any duplicates. I then have a collection of B's that is constantly maintained, but again, no duplicates. B's can then have many A's under one relationship, but there can be overlap; B1 and B2 can both have A1, A2 and A3. Then there is a subcollection within that first relationship, where B1 can "select" A1 and A3 from the original example list and B2 can "select" A2 and A3. This is all assuming that B1 and B2 only know about A1-3 and don't have access to select anything outside of that range.

Having this scenario, my only conclusion was to have two relationships on the same object, as being able to select A1 in B1 would then select it for B2, as well, which is not the intended functionality.

Please question my logic!

Comment: Could you also post the definition of `relationship_a` and `relationship_b`, i.e. their models?

Comment: @vee Sure. They're added.

Comment: I'm very confused at the moment with your added description; Trying to understand it really!  Can you also tell us what is that is not working, possibly a rails console output of what you've tried.